# Replica database is not accessible in Read Scale Availability Group in SQL Server 2017 Standard edition

Tags: high-availability, sql-server-2017

I'm looking into ways of replicating databases from On-Premise environments to Azure and one of the options I found was setting up a Read-Scale availability group.

The reason I'm using a Read-Scale and not an Always On availability group, is because I don't won't to use SQL Server Enterprise edition due to the cost.

I followed a tutorial from Microsoft ([MS TUTORIAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-read-scale-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017)) to set this all up and in the end, I think I got it working as my database appeared on the Azure environment.

However, the problem is that my replica always stays in the `Synchronizing` state - which is probably due to the fact I chose Asynchronous Replication by using the `AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT` command - but even worse is that I can't access the database itself.
Each time I try to fire a query against it, it comes back with an `Object is not accessible` exception.

After some reading, I found that the cause of this might be because my replica doesn't have a secondary role. Trying to set this via the `... SECONDARY_ROLE({ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = ALL})...` command, clearly states that this feature is not available in the Standard version of SQL Server.

My whole confusion comes from the fact that on the Microsoft documentation ([MS DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/read-scale-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017)), it says that `With availability groups, one or more secondary replicas can be configured to support read-only access to secondary databases.` which is exactly what I'm not succeeding in.

Did anybody have the same issue, or knows how to configure the Read-Scale availability group on SQL Server Standard so my second replica is accessible and readable as well?

P.S. I did look at the actual SQL Replication with Transaction Replication, but there are quite a bit of moving parts there, so I'm exploring all options before making a decision.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a twitter conversation I found out that you will need to create a snapshot of the database in Secondary Replica in order to read from there.

Please read this tweeter [thread](https://twitter.com/DBArgenis/status/1205226659395198976).

I also added a suggestion in the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/39254050-documentation-update-read-scale-availability-grou) channel to fix the documentation.